# Making a figure appear only at the end of slide

Tags: floats, presentations, pause

I am using the following code to position a figure according to x-y coordinates:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text...
\pause
\begin{textblock*}{4.2cm}(7.5cm,6.2cm) % {block width} (coords)
\includegraphics[width=4.2cm]{file}
\end{textblock*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, the figure and the text appear simultaneously, despite the \pause command.
How do I make it appear after the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if I understood your question completly, but did you know that first comes the text next page the pciture in a presentation like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\visible<1>{Some text...}
%\pause
\begin{textblock*}{3.2cm}(7.5cm,6.2cm) % {block width} (coords)
\visible<2>{\includegraphics[width=4.2cm]{example-image-b}}
\end{textblock*}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(then `\visible` might be what you are looking for)
[image]

EDIT: Another Solution with \itemize:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
\item[] {Some text...}
    \pause

\item[] \begin{textblock*}{3.2cm}(7.5cm,6.2cm) % {block width} (coords)
        \visible<2>{\includegraphics[width=4.2cm]{example-image-b}}
        \end{textblock*}
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]